# Hide sheets based on user and date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a binder with 12 sheets, one for each month of the year. This workbook is shared with several people and I would like the designated read-only people to see only the past month, the current month and the month following the current month. But that people with write rights can see and modify the entire workbook.

Comment: It's not possible if a user with write access opens the sheet and unhides all of the sheets while the user with read-only access is viewing then they will be able to see everything too. The only way around it would be to create a separate read-only sheet and query the main sheet to import the data you want.

Comment: @JamesD the only problem here is *when* the query is made - external sheets can't be modified by a trigger and people with read-only access can't run scripts either.

Comment: What are 'external sheets'? If you mean editing a spreadsheet other than the one with the script in it, then you can use an installed trigger to make changes to any spreadsheet you have edit premissions for. From a bound script in a spreadsheet, you can modify any other spreadsheet that you have edit access to. Again, people with read-only access can trigger installed triggers.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, this is not possible to do.*

#### More Information:

Google Sheets *does* have the ability to hide/show different sheets, and also has the ability to change these when the Sheet is opened. There are two problems with your situation, however:

1. The only way to run functions on the opening of the Sheet is if the user opening the sheet has edit permissions; read-only is not enough.
2. The changes apply to the whole Sheet, not just one user.

**Let's suppose the following scenario:**

You have a script which checks the permission status of a person that opens the file, and hides all sheets for them except the past, current and following month. Something like this:

```psuedo
function permissionChanging() :
    user = userThatOpenedTheFile;

    if userThatOpenedTheFile.Permission = read-only:
        sheets.hide(all-sheets-except-past-current-and-following)
    else if userThatOpenedTheFile.Permission = write:
        sheets.show(all)
```

Now let's conisder two users:

- User A, a user with read-only access to the sheet.
- User B, a user with write access.

Now, if User A opens the file, as they only have read-only access, the function won't run - [as explained in the script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions).

Let us now assume, for the thought experiment, that User A *was* able to run the function:

When User A opens the Sheet, the function would run, and all Sheets will be hidden except for the current, previous and following months. They can happily look at the sheet in this current form.

Now, User B opens the form, *before User A has closed it*. The script runs again - now, it unhides all sheets. Because the Spreadsheet is stored in the Cloud, the changes are applied ***to all viewers of the sheet*** - so now, as User A *already* has the sheet open, the changed propagate to their view and now they can see all the Sheets.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers | Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

  - [Simple Triggers - Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)
  - [Simple Triggers - `onEdit(e)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)