# Specific permission on the specific sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have a report files, Sales Report.
It contains some sheets. is there any way to set permission for specific people to view and edit certain sheets only?

Comment: Not possible. Sheets are either viewable by everyone, or viewable by no-one. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61009198/11551468) for more details.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want, you might have to create seperate spreadsheets, (for each sales division?) viewable and editable by only the people you specify.  And these sheets could be filled automatically from your one "master" sheet.  Then, if you created new columns in these subordinate sheets, for people to edit/add/change data, the master sheet could pull these changes (with ImportRange) to update the master sheet.  A messy workaround, but possible...  Otherwise using scripts and OnEdit functions might be a cleaner solution, if you want tog go with scripts.